# Can Artifactory connect to a secure Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: authentication, amazon-s3, artifactory

Can Artifactory proxy to a secure Amazon S3 bucket? We are hosting some static libraries on S3, but we want to keep them secure.  Is there a plugin or built-in way for Artifactory to use the Access Key and Secret Key to make requests to the Amazon S3 bucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artifactory currently uses BASIC HTTP to authenticate to remote repos. This does not work with S3, so you may look into using a gateway service (such as, www.s3auth.com)

You may wish to open a request at http://issues.jfrog.com and we will look into adding this, as it seems like a very sensible addition.

Comment: I've created a ticket: https://issues.jfrog.org/jira/browse/RTFACT-5377

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory supports S3 storage natively as of 3.6.

- http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/S3+Object+Storage

> #### Support any S3 compatible distributed file system
>
> Arifactory's support is based on the S3 protocol. Any provider that
>   uses S3, such as Ceph, Swift and others, will also be supported by
>   Artifactory. With support for AWS S3 version 4, you can sign AWS
>   requests using Signature Version 4.